# Does openssl_decrypt use any network calls on PHP running on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am using PHP function openssl_encrypt for encrypting chat messages. It's working fine when I have internet access, but when I run the same code on my Ubuntu Server that is not connected to the Internet it is slow.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction for troubleshooting this? Does openssl_decrypt use any network calls on PHP running on Ubuntu?

**Encrypting message:**

```
$inp_text = "SOME TEXT THAT WILL BE ENCRYPTED";
$get_current_channel_encryption_key = "SOME ENCRYPTION KEY";

$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($inp_text, $cipher, $get_current_channel_encryption_key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $get_current_channel_encryption_key, $as_binary=true);
$ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );
```

**Decrypting message:**

```
$get_message_text = "SOME ENCRYPTED MESSAGE";
$get_current_channel_encryption_key = "SOME ENCRYPTION KEY";

$c = base64_decode($get_message_text);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
$hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
$ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
$original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $get_current_channel_encryption_key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $get_current_channel_encryption_key, $as_binary=true);
if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac))//PHP 5.6+ timing attack safe comparison
{
    $get_message_text = "$original_plaintext";
}
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. But how are you running this? Via CLI or via a local web server? I'm a going to guess that it's a local web server, and that that web server is configured to look up something via the internet [eg: reverse DNS for the connection] and it's timing out.

Comment: Its running on a local web server. 
Thank you for your reply.